# How does $\frac{\cos x}{1-\cos^2x}=\frac23$ become $\cos x=\frac12$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm sure its just gaps in my trig knowledge, however I cant seem to find a similar example easily.

The circled part of the problem is the simplification I'm having trouble with.[image]

I understand where the identity is coming from, what I'm having trouble with is how it is getting eliminated. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: **Hint :** $$\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}=\frac{2}{3} \Longrightarrow 3\cos(x)=2(1-\cos^2(x))\Longrightarrow 3X=2(1-X^2)$$ where $X=\cos(x)$.

Comment: rewrite 2nd line as a quadratic equation in $\cos x$. The equation has two roots, one root is $\frac12$, the other root is $-2$ which one can forget.

Comment: The downvote received is probably due to not using MathJax and posting pictures of math. Here is a guide you can follow to avoid future downvotes (and downvoters) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

$$2 \cot x \csc x=\frac{4}{3}$$
$$\cot x \csc x=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{1}{\sin x}=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$\frac{\cos x}{1-\cos^2 x}=\frac{2}{3}$$
set $\cos x= y$
$$\frac{y}{1-y^2}=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$2y^2+3y-2=0\to y=\frac{1}{2};\;y=-2$$
$$\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\to x=\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$$
$\cos x=-2$ is discarded because has no real solutions.